# What is hypervisor? examples for type1 and type2

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hypervisor

What is hypervisor, and what are the differences between type1 and type2?
Examples for type1 and type2 ? Most questions out there are about the difference between type1 and type2, and the definitions are a bit loosely.

Answer (score 1):

Debates between type 1 and type 2 happen because hypervisors don't neatly fit in those categories.

[ESXi is a small dedicated kernel that removed general operating system components](https://www.slideshare.net/CaronteDark/transitioning-to-esxi). It has its own drivers and so has a hardware comparability list. You can't run any program on it, the console is for troubleshooting and not the preferred way of accessing it.

[Hyper-V has a root partition that runs Windows and has direct access to devices.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-architecture)   Root creates child partitions, so it is not strictly accurate to say the hypervisor creates Hyper-V guests. And you can run any Windows role on that root partition. It get put in the type-1 category because you are basically booting a "bare metal VM". A general purpose OS running guests sounds a little like type-2, however.

I don't find an academic definition of type 1 and 2 nearly as interesting as block diagrams and other descriptions of actual hypervisor components.